# Swift : Sort array by natural order

Tags: ios, sorting, swift

I'm having an dictionary with order here:

```
var pickerData = [
    "en":"abc",
    "jp":"xyz",
    "fr":"gya",
    "zh-CN":"uio"]
```

But when i println() pickerData.keys.array , the order is not like thit. 
I want to sort pickerData.keys.array by order above.
Is it posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are not an ordered data structure.  Arrays are.  So taking the keys from an unordered data structure will result in an unordered result.  You'll need to create your own OrderedDictionary, which isn't that hard to do.

Here is a project with an example of an ordered dictionary: https://github.com/lithium3141/SwiftDataStructures

Here is an article explaining the whole thing if you care for the details: http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/

Answer (score 1):

This is how you sort array of keys:

```
let sortedKeys = sorted(pickerData.keys.array, { 
    (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 < s2
})
```

Just replace the return statement to change the sort logic to the one which match your requirements.

Comment: It's not work. I need only natural sort like i write above. order by the defined dictionary

Comment: The dictionary won't guarantee any order. You should consider using arrays or maybe create your own class to keep reference to sort order. What do you mean by not working, can you explain? I try it in playground and it works.

Comment: I tried in playground too but it sorted by alphabet. You don't understand my question? i want it sort by defined dictionary with natural order like: `"en","jp","fr","zh-CN"` not alphabet like : `"en","fr","jp","zh-CN"` , i just edited my question for you don't have misunderstand that i need sort by alphabet.

Comment: @TomSawyer: A dictionary *has no order*.

Comment: Tks. So that means i need to i rewrite my code like : `[0:["en":"abc"],1:["jp":"123"]` to give an order but xcode seem take very long time to process my code if with long list :(

Comment: There is more solution. You can keep dict with just one value and key in array - array has order. You can also create new class where you have dictionary as the one from the question and array which will keep just a keys, the keys will be ordered by default.

Comment: @Greg That is the solution in my answer above.  Create an Ordered dictionary using the examples in my answer, and performance will be much better than trying to create an array of tuples.  And the array of tuples you lose the ability to reference items by a key.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a sorted version of the keys array, taking into account that it's an immutable array, you have to:

- copy to a mutable variable
- sort in place using the `sort` method

This is the code:

```
var array = pickerData.keys.array as [String]
array.sort(<)
```

Now `array` is sorted alphabetically. The reason why a copy of the keys array is needed is that `sort` operates in place, which is obviously not possible on an immutable array.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 4 and 5 this has got a lot easier:

```
for mySortedKey in pickerData.keys.sorted() {
    [....]
}
```